# Unintuitive results in model comparison

Tags: regression, anova, model-selection

I am running an experiment for some time now and currently I am in the process of analyzing my data. At first I was unsure about which model fits my needs, but after receiving some much appreciated help from the CV community, I decided that Mixed Effect Binomial Regression is the way to go.

In my experiment, each participant is assigned to a condition and then goes through 8 trials. In each trial, he/she is shown a stimulus and then I record whether they exhibit a certain behavior after that.

My model tries to predict *Success* (binary variable indicating whether they exhibited the target behavior, with values 0 and 1) using *Condition* (factor, with values *experimental* and *control*), *Trial* (numeric, with values 1-8), and *Participant* (string).

I have fitted two models so far, where the first one predicts *Success* using fixed effects for *Condition*, *Trial*, and a random effect for *Participant*. After fitting it, this is the sumary table I get in R:

[image]

As you can see nothing seems significant. However, it is also justifiable to include an interaction term between *Condition* and *Trial* into the model. After fitting this updated model, I get this summary table:

[image]

Now both the condition and the trial are significant. Furthermore, I did an anova to test whether there is any significant difference between these two models, and I got this:

[image]

So the situation is that there is no significant difference between these two models, however in one of them both of the predictors are significant! This looks very unintuitive to me, while it also makes unclear which model to select to base my analysis.

Do you agree that this seems a bit strange? Do you maybe have any ideas about the reasons behind it?

Comment: Your model assumes a strictly linear association between the numeric trial value and log-odds of success. That’s pretty rigid. Think about how you expect the trial number to be associated with success and model accordingly. For example, treating trial number as a categorical predictor, maybe coded as ordinal. Or model it as continuous (as you are now) but with a regression spline for flexibility in fitting.

Comment: @EdM Thank you for your answer. I tried fitting the model again using splines (of degree up to 3), but the resulting models fitted my data worse than the linear one. To be honest, it seems like the relationship is linear though, as trials progress, participants get better. I tried the ordinal suggestion, but perhaps I don't have enough data, since I got an error that the model failed to converge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you're running lots of tests, the probability that you occasionally find significant results even if nothing meaningful goes on is quite high.
2. Andrew Gelman and Hal Stern show here...
   https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/000313006X152649
   ...that "The Difference Between “Significant” and “Not Significant” is not Itself Statistically Significant". Even two models that have quite different assessments of the significance of certain parameters that occur in both of them may be so similar regarding their fit of the data that the data cannot decide between them, i.e., that the more complex one is not significantly better than the simpler one.
3. Overall I don't think you have any indication that any of the significances you found is meaningful. (This doesn't mean that nothing is going on; you may test the first model against an uninformative intercept only model to see whether your variables together explain something even if the data are too weak to tell you which variable exactly does the trick. Also you may ask whether a potential trial effect may be nonlinear or non-monotonic; not sure what your trials are, but the numerical coding may be inappropriate in a generalised linear model.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have only used my data to fit these two models, so I hope I don't get these results due to randomness. I fitted the intercept only model, then compared it to the others, and the result was that they are significantly different. I guess this means that my variables hold some information. I also tried fitting another model using splines for the trials, and only the condition was significant, but the model fit was worse overall. I then tried having trials as a factor, but I had to drop the interaction to fit it, and nothing was significant

Comment: The problem is that one of the models support my hypothesis, while the other doesn't, so I am very tempted to just go with the one that works for me. However, I feel like cheating a bit, but I don't know if this is really the case

Comment: @John_P If you don't report all you have tried, it would be cheating indeed. As scientists we should be interested in finding out the truth unbiased by what we hope for. You are seemingly very aware that your major reason for potentially choosing one model over the other is that it gives you what you hope for.

Answer (score 3):

This is mostly an extended comment on the answer from @Christian Hennig (+1), which covers the critical points and which I think you should accept.

It's very tempting to think that a "significant difference" "supports" your hypothesis. That's not strictly how frequentist significance tests work. A small p-value *argues against a null* hypothesis, but (as pointed out in Point 2 of Christian Hennig's answer) it doesn't necessarily argue *for* any specific alternative hypothesis. A lack of "significance" doesn't mean the predictor is unimportant, just that your combination of data and model couldn't document its "significance" by an arbitrary (if widely used) criterion.

If (before seeing the data) you suspected that the association of `success` with `Trial` number might depend on `Condition`, then it would have made sense to start with a model containing the interaction. To evaluate if the fixed effects in that model add anything to a null model, compare that model against one with only the random intercepts--as Christian Hennig recommends in Point 3. If the null hypothesis of no fixed effects isn't tenable, then at least you have found something of potential interest. I suspect that you have, even in the model without the interaction term that showed neither predictor *on its own* to be "significant."

You are in a common situation where "the data are too weak to tell you which variable exactly does the trick," as he nicely put it. In that situation, attempts to improve the model with additional terms (splines, interaction terms, etc.) might not add enough to make up for the extra degrees of freedom that you use up, in terms of "significance."

Do, however, see whether the model makes sense in terms of your data. One way to interpret the interaction term coefficient of `-0.230` for `ConditionExperimental:Trial` is in the context of the slope of `+0.247` for `Trial`, which is the change per `Trial` in `ConditionControl`. That suggests an increasing probability of success with `Trial` in `ConditionControl`, but essentially *no*  increasing probability of success with `Trial` in `ConditionExperimental` (`0.247 - 0.230 = 0.017`). Is that how your data look? Does that make sense based on your knowledge of the subject matter? Comparing the data against the model is typically more useful than just staring at reported coefficient values.

Your results only seem counterintuitive because you are so highly focused on the arbitrary p = 0.05 cutoff for "significance." The interaction term might not be "significant" by that criterion, but that doesn't mean it's unimportant in the context of your study. This is one reason why many come to prefer Bayesian models that can provide [credible intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credible_interval) for parameters without the all-or-none fixation on arbitrary null-probability cutoffs.

Comment: Also if you use Bayesian modelling, if you ultimately want to make a statement that there's evidence in the data (or not) that this-or-that variable has a meaningful effect, you need some kind of more or less arbitrary cutoff for when you say this. This is not a problem of frequentism but rather a problem of people wanting to make (and to read) binary statements.

Comment: @ChristianHennig the desire for binary statements is certainly the fundamental problem. That just seems to be more of an issue in practice with frequentism and the near-universal requirement for statements like "statistical significance was accepted at p < 0.05 in 2-sided tests." In a Bayesian context, my sense is that it's somewhat easier to present and discuss the quantitative estimates without a dichotomy.

Comment: @ChristianHennig Thank you both very much for your help. I understand that interpreting the fitted model and inspecting whether it makes sense is more reasonable than just saying that the p-value is <0.05, but in my field at least, I find it very hard for reviewers to appreciate "non-significant" results. They expect to see a definitive claim, which I guess is related to the fact that statistics is used as a "validation" tool. However, can you suggest any resources about designing and interpreting models? I want to become a better modeler and make good and appropriate use of statistics.

Comment: Perhaps something with experimental case studies and how particular design choices can accommodate certain insights. I a open to Bayesian statistics too, I know the basic stuff about priors and posteriors, some mcmc, variational inference, but I am not in place to design good models by any means, so an introduction to Bayesian modeling would be better I think.

Comment: @John_P I'd recommend that you try Frank Harrell's [course notes](https://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf) and [book](https://hbiostat.org/rms/), entitled "Regression Modeling Strategies." Those present issues faced in real-world studies, like yours, where data might be limited. The approach is frequentist, but my sense from your question and comments is that material like what's in those references is what you need first. It covers multiple types of models. The [website](https://hbiostat.org) provides links to more related resources. Also search this Cross Validated site for recommendations.